# Training Large Datasets (e.g.: 30GB+) on the Cloud?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, google-cloud-platform, bigdata

I'm working on a Kaggle project and I'm stuck at the first hurdle. The dataset is 30GB of images. I want to be able to train my model on some kind of cloud solution, I downloaded it on a Virtual Machine, got it in a Google Cloud Storage bucket, but anything from there seems to trip up with too much data. I've tried:

- Mounting my Google Drive in Colab and reading it off there (notebook cant
  handle that much data)
- Rendering from GCS itself (can only download and open single files at
  a time, but this is the closest I got)
- Moving the whole thing over to Google DataLab and downloading from
  GCS there (slows to the point its unusable, having difficulty opening
  the notebook now)

This seems like it would be a fairly common ML use case, just running operations, visualising and then training on cloud data? My assumption is using something like BigQuery isn't viable given its image data and not able to fit into a structured dataset. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: How do I train large datasets of images on cloud infrastructure, seeing as though there doesn't seem to be a way to run directly on the storage bucket?

Comment: Google Colab is not free for everyone GPU for every cheapskate to come along and use its resources just coz they don't wanna buy a GPU. Colab is meant to be a research platform. If you want to train using such a large dataset just download it locally and run your computer overnight. Unless you want to sell your model to google, a dataset of 10 gb is more than enough.

Answer (score 1):

I dealt with the same problem few weeks ago and I found two good ways to do it in Google Cloud Platform.

The first one is creating a VM instance with one of the public deep learning images, you have many versions with different deep learning settings. You have to create a new instance, go the boot disk, there you choose "deep learning on Linux" into the operating systems, and then select the version it fits you better. Then is up you choose or not a GPU to speed up training. Notice that with the VM instance stopped you can change almost all the hardware, so as the GPUs are expensive I recommend using those only during training or whenever you need computational resources. I can also suggest you to use an SSD disk to store the dataset due to the fact that you are using an image dataset and it will speed up your input pipeline, i.e. your image data ingestion. I can give you some more hints if you choose this way, for example to use an attached disk to store the dataset so you can move it from one instance to another easily.

The second one is creating an AI Jupyter notebook. This is located inside the AI platform and there are many [tutorials](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs) to get in touch with them. They are really useful as they are a VM instance with a deep learning image as a backend and a Jupyterlab as a frontend. It makes easy to launch trainings to people who's not used to the command line interface so deep, but they are a bit more expensive if I'm not wrong.

I hope it helps and do not hesitate to ask further.